# Go to each link stored in string and list all PDF links

Tags: vb.net, web-scraping, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

My first attempt to create program.

I am trying to go to website, get all links, after that proceed to each link and get all links that are ending with

```
.pdf
```

I am able to get all needed links. Now I want to proceed to each link and search for PDF files.

```
Imports HtmlAgilityPack

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim mainUrl As String = "xxx"
        Dim htmlDoc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlWeb().Load(mainUrl) '< - - - Load the webage into htmldocument

        Dim listLinks As New List(Of String)

        Dim srcs As HtmlNodeCollection = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='products-list-page']//a") '< - - - select nodes with links
        For Each src As HtmlNode In srcs

            ' Store links in array
            listLinks.Add(src.Attributes("href").Value)

        Next

        ' Here I am attempting to through each link and get listed all .pdf links

        'get the array from the list.
        Dim arrayLinks() As String = listLinks.ToArray()

        'Console.Read()

        Dim scrapedsrcs As HtmlNodeCollection = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='dl-items']//a") '< - - - select nodes with links
        For Each scrapedlink As HtmlNode In scrapedsrcs

            ' Show links in console
            Console.WriteLine(scrapedlink.Attributes("href").Value) '< - - - Print urls

        Next

    End Sub

End Module
```

How to make it happen? Can somebody give me a hint?

---

**EDIT:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you did not iterate each product links and download the html to scan for the pdf file download links.

This is done by :

```
For Each productLink As String In listLinks
    Dim prodDoc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlWeb().Load(productLink)

    Dim scrapedsrcs As HtmlNodeCollection = prodDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='dl-items']//a") '< - - - select nodes with links

    If scrapedsrcs IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each scrapedlink As HtmlNode In scrapedsrcs     
            ' Show links in console
            Console.WriteLine($"-- {scrapedlink.Attributes("href").Value}") '< - - - Print urls     
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Secondly, the `a` link to download the pdf is contained inside a `div` instead of `ul`. So to select the nodes, use :

```
prodDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='dl-items']//a")
```

Or you can specify `*` to select by class regardless of element like :

```
prodDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='dl-items']//a")
```

Comment: Wow! I am speechless! Than you a million!

Comment: I would like to ask just one question. Why it prints one empty string? I have added a screenshot to my original question.

Comment: Because there is no link, which you can see either in your program (when you debug) or if you go to the website. You really need to look for answers to those questions you are having, I get the impression you are not being curious.

Comment: Oh yes sure, sorry. I was working on VBScript solution previously that is actually working already. Trying to understand how VB.net now. In VBScript I was getting all the links by filtering 4 digits from the Right ".pdf". That's why There were no empty ones.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not doing anything with those links, why not simply write it nice and short?

Like:

```
Imports HtmlAgilityPack

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim htmlDoc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlWeb().Load("https: //www.nordicwater.com/products/waste-water/")
        For Each src As HtmlNode In htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='products-list-page']//a")
            htmlDoc = New HtmlWeb().Load(src.Attributes("href").Value)
            Dim LinkTest As HtmlNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='dl-items']/a")
            If LinkTest IsNot Nothing AndAlso LinkTest.Attributes("href").Value.Length > 0 Then Console.WriteLine(LinkTest.Attributes("href").Value)
        Next
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thanks! As a next step I would like to try to download all the files. I will try to get it working tomorrow. I have experience only in VBA and a little bit in VB.net. Got stuck on loop logic with this one...